# xesmf regridder to regrid xarray dataset partially incorrectly regridded (speckled)

Tags: python, python-xarray

I have regridded my xarray dataset from lat/lon to UTM. However I have a speckled appearance in the data that is not present before reprojection. Does anyone know why or how I might fix it?

My code is:

```py
    # Create the 2D meshgrid
    xx, yy = np.meshgrid(x_values, y_values)

    # Create a transformer to perform the coordinate transformation
    transformer = Transformer.from_crs(epsg, 4326, always_xy=True)

    # Perform the coordinate transformation
    new_xx, new_yy = transformer.transform(xx, yy)
    ds = ds.rename({'XLAT': 'lat', 'XLON': 'lon'})

    # Step 1: Create the regridder from the source grid (latitude-longitude) to the target grid (UTM)
    regridder = xe.Regridder(ds, xr.Dataset(data_vars={},
                                            coords={'lon': (['y', 'x'], new_xx),
                                            'lat': (['y', 'x'], new_yy)}),
                            'bilinear', periodic=True)
```

[image]

Comment: I have reverted to using ds.interp onto the coordinates of the grid projected back into the native coordinate system. Using ds.interp doesn't give the above effect